# output everything between specific string ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a line within a file which is structured as follows:

```
<IncludePath>..\..\somethingB\include;..\..\..\somethingA\Source;$(IncludePath)<\IncludePath>
```

I'm just trying to print everything between IncludePath> and $(IncludePath)

```
line.scan(/<IncludePath>(.*)$(IncludePath)/m)
print line
```

But I get the complete line together with the tags. I would like just the string between tags. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you get anything? `$` means the end of line. Is it XML (it looks like XML)? As a starter, I will advise to use lazy dot matching (:-D): `/<IncludePath>(.*?)\$\(IncludePath\)/m`

Comment: yes I'm getting everything. Yes it is xml. I'm not using xml parser because it's just this one case I have to parse a simple line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
> string = "<IncludePath>..\..\somethingB\include;..\..\..\somethingA\Source;$(IncludePath)<\IncludePath>"
> string[/<IncludePath>(.*?)\$\(IncludePath\)/m, 1]
#=> ".... omethingBinclude;...... omethingASource;"
```

**OR** as  [mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824855/output-everything-between-specific-string-ruby/33825057?noredirect=1#comment55416158_33825057) suggested you can use :

```
> string[/(?<=<IncludePath>).*?(?=\$\(IncludePath\))/m]
#=> ".... omethingBinclude;...... omethingASource;"
```

Comment: @milexy86 : glad to help you :)

Comment: Consider using lookbehinds and lookaheads to get an exact match: `string[/(?<=<IncludePath>).*?(?=\$\(IncludePath\))/m]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa : yeah I forgot that can be also possible any ways thanks for the point answer is updated :)